# Properties of $f_n (x) := \frac{n}{nx + 1}$ (Integrable, converge pointwise, pointwise limit integrable)

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $f_n(x)$ is defined as $$f_n (x) := \frac{n}{nx + 1}.$$

Is each $f_n(x)$ integrable?
And do $f_n(x)$ converge pointwise?
If yes, then is pointwise limit $f$ of $f_n(x)$ integrable?

The domain of these functions is [0,1]. <- I forgot..

I have not used this site, so I don't be good at handling.. sorry.

Comment: What is the domain of $f_n$?

Comment: Please tell us the domain of these functions!

Comment: Oh, I didn't tell domain.
I'm very SORRY..
The domain is [0,1].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your 
$f_{n}$ s
are integrable. You just need considering the 
$\ln$ function.

Second, for the next question please tend the 
$n$ to infinity.

Finally, if the above 
$f_{n}$ s 
are pointwise in order to answer the third question you domain must be compact set and also the sequence have to be a decreasing one.

Comment: Certainly, if the convergence is monotone, the limit is integrable, but why does the convergence *need* to be monotone?

Comment: Chapter7 Walter Rudin Principles of Mathematical Analysis

Comment: I don't have that at hand, but the implication is that **if** the sequence is a decreasing one, **then** we can use dominated convergence; and **if** the sequence is an increasing one, **then** we can use monotone convergence. However, the sequence need not be monotone for the pointwise limit of $f_n$ to be integrable.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense your first remark. Unfortunately, these days I do not have time to scrutinize the questions closely. But, your second part is competely true.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't tell the domain of $f_n$.

Comment: The domain is [0,1]

Comment: Thus, your domain is compact so my hint can help you answer this question. Good luck.